# Powershell Pipe to Switch Statement to format a phone number

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am attempting to query AD to get the phone number for a user then format it to a standard format (###-####).  I'm using a Switch statement because I've seen the number in a handful of different formats. With the way I have my code set up though I am getting an error: "The term Switch is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file..."

Here's the code:

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADUser $User.Email.split("@")[0] -Properties * -Server $DC
$User.'Phone Number' = $ADInfo.telephoneNumber | Switch -regex ($_) {
    '^\d{5}$'                     
    {                        
        "{0:38#-####}" -f $_
        break
    }
    '^\d{7}$' 
    {
        "{0:###-####}" -f $_
        break
    }
    default
    {
        break
    } 

}
```

Am I misunderstanding how the pipeline works? I suppose I could just save this info to a temp variable and then enter a Switch statement but this seemed like an effective way to use the pipeline.

Anyhow, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Mathias R. Jessen, here's an example of how to use `Switch` without having to iterate through things with a `ForEach` loop, or piping anything to it.

Switch will iterate an array on its own, so there's no need to nest it in a loop, or even pipe anything in this case. It can be done as such:

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADUser $User.Email.split("@")[0] -Properties * -Server $DC
    $User.'Phone Number' = Switch -regex ($ADInfo.telephoneNumber) {
        '^\d{5}$'                     
        {                        
            "{0:38#-####}" -f $_
        }
        '^\d{7}$' 
        {
            "{0:###-####}" -f $_
        }
    }
```

Aside from that I would recommend using `Continue` instead of `Break`. Further example of when `continue` would be used within the `Switch` scriptblock:

```
$TestData = @('John.Doe@Company.Com','JDoe','(555)867-5309','Taco Tuesday')
Switch -regex ($TestData){
    '@' {"$_ is an email address.";continue}
    '^[+()\-\d\s]+$' {"$_ is a phone number.";continue}
    default {"$_ is unknown."}
}
```

Here we have something being done in the `default` block, so we want to include a `continue` statement in the previous cases so that if a match is found it moves to the next item in the array, and does not execute the `default` case. The output of that would be:

```
John.Doe@Company.com is an email address.
JDoe is unknown.
(555)867-5309 is a phone number.
Taco Tuesday is unknown.
```

Comment: Based on your comment in Mathias's answer, this is what I went with.  For whatever reason I did have to convert the .telephoneNumber to an integer but I think that might be because some of these phone numbers are formatted correctly and PowerShell interprets them as strings.

Answer (score 7):

> Am I misunderstanding how the pipeline works?

Yes.

The pipeline can only pipe stuff to *commands* - and `switch` is not a command, it's a language keyword.

You can wrap your `switch` statement in a `ForEach-Object` block and pipe the input to that:

```
$User.'Phone Number' = $ADInfo.telephoneNumber | ForEach-Object {
    Switch -regex ($_) {
        '^\d{5}$'                     
        {                        
            "{0:38#-####}" -f $_
        }
        '^\d{7}$' 
        {
            "{0:###-####}" -f $_
        }
    }
}
```

As [Ansgar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099801/powershell-pipe-to-switch-statement-to-format-a-phone-number/42099852?noredirect=1#comment71369926_42099852), the `break` statements here are redundant (and not required), since your test cases are mutually exclusive

Comment: Note that `break` has no function here.

Comment: Even simpler, `Switch` can iterate and loop, so this just becomes `$User.'Phone Number' = Switch -regex ($ADInfo.telephoneNumber){ ... }`. Also, due to the way `break` can mess with a variety of loops you may want to consider replacing `break` with `continue`. Lastly, since your regex matches are so specific you could remove the break/continue lines entirely, as well as the `default` case since it is then empty.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `break` will not affect `ForEach-Object` in this case, only applies to the `switch` statement. You should add an answer showing a `switch` statement with array input though :-)